# Maximum likelihood estimation using R

Tags: multiple-regression, maximum-likelihood, economics

I have a multiple linear regression, that I want to estimate using a MLE approach. I would like to make the fit using a Beta distribution, with parameters u and v. How can I do this using R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beta regression is implemented in betareg CRAN package, see [1], and also CRAN webpage.

[1] https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/vignettes/betareg.pdf